# How to change the memory to test eclipse plug-in

Tags: testing, eclipse-plugin, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to test my plug-in, but it always comes up with only 40MB and I keep getting out of memory error. If I change the setting, it doesn't take it. It creates a brand new one with default value as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is that you want some default arguments to be populated automatically for each new PDE launch configuration.

You can do this:

1. Go to preferences -> Plug in development -> Target platform
2. Select the target platform you are using and click edit
3. Click on the arguments tab
4. Add your program and vm arguments and these will be applied to all new launch configurations for that target platform

Here's a screenshot of the preferences page:

[image: Target platform arguments]